# JSON taglib not working?

Tags: json, jsp, taglib

Any one knows if the JSON taglib is still working?

I am including it in my jsp and it gives me an error. This error says this:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: http://www.atg.com/taglibs/json cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application.
```

I've include the json-taglib-0.4.1.jar file in my WEB-INF/lib respository and also include it on the top of my jsp page:

```
<%@taglib prefix="json" uri="http://www.atg.com/taglibs/json"%>
```

But the error appears, and I dont know why. Any one knows how can I add JSON taglib for my jsp page?

Comment: Have you added json-taglib.jar file into the WEB-INF/lib directory of your web-application?

Comment: yes i've added json library to the folder

Answer (score 0):

want to help, BUT level my reputation still does not allow me to do :-), 
because write in answer

I think we must sent listing your web.xml

For example

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
   
<display-name>mon</display-name>



<jsp-config>
  <!-- JSTL Tag Library Local Descriptors -->
  <taglib>
    <taglib-uri>/WEB-INF/jstl/c.tld</taglib-uri>
    <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/jstl/c.tld</taglib-location>
  </taglib>
  <taglib>
    <taglib-uri>/WEB-INF/jstl/fmt.tld</taglib-uri>
    <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/jstl/fmt.tld</taglib-location>
  </taglib>
  <taglib>
    <taglib-uri>/WEB-INF/jstl/fn.tld</taglib-uri>
    <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/jstl/fn.tld</taglib-location>
  </taglib>
  <taglib>
    <taglib-uri>/WEB-INF/jstl/sql.tld</taglib-uri>
    <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/jstl/sql.tld</taglib-location>
  </taglib>
  <taglib>
    <taglib-uri>/WEB-INF/jstl/x.tld</taglib-uri>
    <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/jstl/x.tld</taglib-location>
  </taglib>
  <taglib>
    <taglib-uri>/WEB-INF/jstl/taglib34.tld</taglib-uri>
    <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/jstl/taglib34.tld</taglib-location>
  </taglib>  
</jsp-config>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>main.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

and check build project,
for example IDEA

[image]